# Django freeze after launch celery .delay. how to fix?

Tags: django, celery

Run simple task to print string, and it freezing total without any error, everything is installed.

celery launched, redis working, when it run delay celery app nothing print.

but in django runserver printing once "2,2"

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'src.settings.local')
    
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('src')
    
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
    
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))
```

my tasks.py

```
import os
import datetime
from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task
def testfunc():
    print('EKHASGBDJHGASd')
    return False
```

my launch that func in views

```
testfunc.delay()
```

Celery worker find all tasks, but when launch some tasks, all is freezing, and have no any error, celery worker is quite.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and maybe my solution works for you as well. I found that my problem was in my project `settings.py`. First of all make sure that you define celery variables properly in your `settings.py`:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://{}:{}@{}'.format(
    CELERY_BROKER_USER,
    CELERY_BROKER_PASS,
    CELERY_BORKER_HOST
)
```

If this variable (`CELERY_BROKER_URL`) is defined properly then I think your problem is your `CELERY_BORKER_HOST` and if you define it in wrong way (Example: `CELERY_BROKER_HOST = "localhost:5673/"` instead of `CELERY_BROKER_HOST = "localhost:5672/"`for rabbitmq) then whenever you call `.delay()` it will freeze.

Comment: No i set everything by totur, and i use redis.